# What's the difference between function and function() in C#?

Tags: c#

For example, 
    `Thread t = new Thread(function);`
Why not
    `Thread t = new Thread(function());`
Thank you.

Comment: `function` evaluates to a function. `function()` calls the function and evaluates to its return value. You want to pass a function to `new Thread()` so *it* can call the function, not call it yourself and pass whatever it returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `function` refers the address of a function you can call
- `function()` gets the return
  value of a function
- A third way could be `() => function()` which
  creates a new anonymous function which is calling `function` (a simple wrapper in this case)

Since `function()` returns no other function

```
Thread t = new Thread(function());
```

would not work because a thread needs a function to call. This means you have to use

```
Thread t = new Thread(function);
```

or

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => function());
```

to pass a function to a thread.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

`function` is the delegate of the function (signature) and won't be executed.
`function()` will be executed and you'll get the result  of function in return.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
Thread t = new Thread(function);
```

is a short version of this line:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(function));
```

It constructs a delegate [`ThreadStart`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.113).aspx) from a method name using *Method Group Syntax* introduced in C# 2.

On the other hand, this line

```
Thread t = new Thread(function());
```

creates a thread using a delegate returned by the `function` method. Of course `function` must return `ThreadStart` delegate in order for the above to compile.

Answer (score 1):

**Before I answer, I have a very important question, Why Thread in current version of .Net, use Task and Parallel APIs, which are much cleaner and better abstracted alternatives. For understanding its fine, but not for usage anymore**

Following is the source code of [Thread](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs,3980e012bae82e96) class, check the constructor with only `ThreadStart` delegate, pasting underneath:

```
 [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
        public Thread(ThreadStart start) {
            if (start == null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("start");
            }
            Contract.EndContractBlock();
            SetStartHelper((Delegate)start,0);  //0 will setup Thread with default stackSize
        }
```

Following is the source code for [ThreadStart](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/threadstart.cs,0727d44b66e77625) delegate

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(true)]
    public delegate void ThreadStart();
```

So Thread class just needs a Delegate, with void return and no input, which is what function points to in `Thread t = new Thread(function)`, actually this is a short form, called method grouping, otherwise full fledged form would be creating a `ThreadStart` object, assigning it a function which maps to its signature. Following are the other options:

1. `() => Function()` // Lambda Syntax, use directly in Thread constructor
2. `ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(Function)` // variable `ts` can be used in the Thread constructor

Comment: I was debugging some code written a decade ago. The thread was used in the legacy code. Thank you for answering my question. I will have a look at the Task and Parallel APIs.

Answer (score 0):

function is just the "function" variable

function() evaluates it, and you're passing its return value as parameter to the thread constructor

Comment: What do you mean by function variable